# cookiecutter-django local development with docker

Tags: python, django, docker, cookiecutter-django, cookiecutter

I've never use docker for development on local machine so I have few questions that I didn't find in [documentation](http://cookiecutter-django.readthedocs.io/en/latest/developing-locally-docker.html).

1. After setup I can't figure out how do I can install my packages via pip. I tried:
   `docker-compose -f local.yml run --rm django pip install some-package`. It installed package somewhere, but not in project. Do I need to build every time when I add new package?
2. How to run django managment commands in another thread
   `docker-compose -f local.yml run --rm django python manage.py mycommand` stop `runserver` command that is not convenient
3. Where do I see celery tasks log ?  How to run:

   `celery -A apps.taskapp worker -l info
   celery -A  apps.taskapp beat -l INFO`

   to see debug messages of my tasks

Answer (score 12, accepted):

I am assuming you started your project using the `cookiecutter-django` template.

1. First time setup you run `docker-compose -f local.yml build`. This will install all the dependencies defined in `local.txt`. If you add any customized pip package to either `local.txt` or `base.txt`, you will have to re-build the docker image `docker-compose -f local.yml build.
2. To run any commands in a docker container, you do:

   `docker-compose -f local.yml run django [commands you would like to run]`

Note: in the above command `django` is the name service defined in your local.yml

For example, to apply migrations in docker:

`docker-compose -f local.yml run django python manage.py migrate`

3. To start all services (django/postgres/celery/mailhog/etc) , just run:

   `docker-compose -f local.yml up`

You can inspect the logs of specific running docker container by:

`docker logs -f [name or id of container]`

which you can find out by:

`docker ps`

Comment: when I ran all services with `docker-compose -f local.yml up` , then i did changes in some celery task file and restart celery beat container. But this not worked. Only restart docker-compose helped. This is not very convenient.  Celery is like a part of django container https://github.com/pydanny/cookiecutter-django/blob/master/%7B%7Bcookiecutter.project_slug%7D%7D/compose/local/django/Dockerfile#L30